# iOS in app purchase - "this account does not have permission.."

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Ok here goes trying to explain this as clearly as possible:)

- I have developed an app for a partner.
- They wanted to submit the app under their company so I was given the certs and profiles. I packaged the app ...they submitted and all was fine.
- Now I need to update the app with new content. So all this is done and the client has set up new in App purchase products for the app.

**The Problem:**

When I am testing all of the "product requests" are successful and it displays the description of the product etc.

However when I come to test purchasing with a iTunes test account it does not work. It says

> "This account doesn't have permission to make in app purchases. You
>   can change account permissions in iTunes Connect."

However to try and work out the problem, as a test I quickly set up a "test" app in OUR iTunes account and a new bundle id etc and set up same IAP products. I then changed the app ID for the actual client app to point at this. And this works fine no problem what soever when testing via Xcode on device.

I am at a loss at what is wrong here as when I did the original app all worked as expected as in I was able to use a iTunes test account I had set up to test their app.

Any ideas what might be going on?

regards

ade

Comment: I have the same problem, it works on my iPhone signed with an ad-hoc profile but not on my friends iphone.

Comment: any updates? I got the same issue !

Answer (score 3):

Apparently the test user account needs to be on the same apple developer account as your app!

Comment: i am in the same user account , and faced the same problem.